# Swift - navigation buttons show & hide

Tags: ios, swift

Running into a really weird issue and couldn't find how to fix it. I have tab bar controller based app with 3 view controllers (2 table view controllers and one regular vc), they are Profile, Orders, People. When I sign in, I land on profile and the buttons in the nav bar show properly. As soon as I go to People and come back, the buttons disappear and don't show anymore. Also vice versa is true (going from People to Profile).

This is the additional weird part: if I go from profile to orders, then back, it will show all buttons. Also if I go from profile to orders to people, people shows normally.

Here is the structure:

[image]

In all viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear, I add the following code:

```
let editButton = UIButton()
        editButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 35)
        editButton.setTitle("Edit Profile ", forState: .Normal)
        editButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
        editButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("editButtonPressed"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        let leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem()
        leftBarButton.customView = editButton
        self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton
```

and in the viewWillDisappear, I add:

```
self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
```

All except Orders table view controller doesn't have any of the above code. What is going on? I will be happy to provide more if needed, but this is really all there is to it as far as I understand.

Comment: try moving your code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: Why do you set your bar button to nil?  Is it needed?

Comment: @LeoDabus amazingly this worked! Thank you Leo. Please post this as an answer so that we can help others avoiding placing such code in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear which is a common mistake as i've come see around the internet (hence I followed it)

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:**

1.Show:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView?.alpha = 1.0
```

2.hide:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView?.alpha = 0.0
```